# How to determine a value integer of which MPI-constant it is?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

When I use a mpi_comm_split I print the rank of process in newcomm by using MPI_comm_rank and for outsider process I get MPI_UNDEFINED = 32766 which is normal. I need a way how to know the constant of MPI with a  specific value?

For example here I get -1 and it is MPI_PROC_NULL.

```
    #include<stdio.h>  
    #include"mpi.h"  

    int main(){
    MPI_Init(0,0);
    printf("MPI_COMM_NULL %d",MPI_COMM_NULL);
    MPI_Finalize() ;
   }
```

Comment: Basically you are asking for introspection on macros. You have to do this by hand.

Comment: is there a list of C MPI constant ?

Comment: Probably in the MPI standard.

Comment: Long story short, do not do that. The MPI standard means that code is portable at the source code level, and it is up to the MPI library to decide whether such value should be a macro, a constant or something else.

Comment: FWIW, `MPI_COMM_NULL` is a macro (int) in MPICH and a pointer in Open MPI.

Comment: so how i can know the type of error, the ones returned by function ? Gilles Gouaillardet

Comment: Which function ? Most MPI subroutines return an `int`